# zeromq persistence patterns

Tags: python, persistent, zeromq

Who has to manages the persistent in the ZeroMQ?

When we use the ZeroMQ clients in Python language, what are the plug-ins/modules available to manage the persistent?

I would like to know the patterns to use the ZeroMQ.

Comment: The ZeroMQ Guide has a persistence pattern called Titanic. It's based on a pattern called MajorDomo. You can also make your own persistent queues quite easily. However before you start adding persistence, though, it's worth understanding your reliability requirements in detail. The Guide covers this in depth. Just adding persistence somewhere will not give you reliability.

Comment: @PieterHintjens Please add this as an answer. I almost missed it. And its the most valuable resource on this page.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, Zeromq does not have any persistence. It is out of scope for it and needs to be handled by the end user. Just like serializing the message. 
In C#, I have used db4o to add persistence. Typically I persist the object in its raw state, then serialize it and send it to ZMQ socket. Btw, this was for PUB/SUB pair.

Answer (score 3):

On the application ends you can persist accordingly, for example I've built a persistance layer in node.js which communicated to back-end php calls and via websockets.

The persistance aspect held messages for a certain period of time (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live) this was to give clients a chance to connect. I used in-memory data structures but I toyed with the idea of using redis to gain on-disk persistance.

Answer (score 2):

We needed to persist the received messages from a subscriber before processing them. The messages are received in a separate thread and stored on disk, while the persisted message queue is manipulated in the main thread.

The module is available at: https://pypi.org/project/persizmq. From the documentation:

```
import pathlib

import zmq

import persizmq

context = zmq.Context()
subscriber = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
subscriber.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
subscriber.connect("ipc:///some-queue.zeromq")

persistent_dir = pathlib.Path("/some/dir")
storage = persizmq.PersistentStorage(persistent_dir=persistent_dir)

def on_exception(exception: Exception)->None:
    print("an exception in the listening thread: {}".format(exception))

with persizmq.ThreadedSubscriber(
    callback=storage.add_message, subscriber=subscriber, 
    on_exception=on_exception):

    msg = storage.front()  # non-blocking
    if msg is not None:
        print("Received a persistent message: {}".format(msg))
        storage.pop_front()
```